# Batch processing clip tools

Tags: qgis, clip, batch

I am using QGIS 3.30

I have a Layer of 14 farms, digitised as polygons.
I have digitised polygons of 6 different land use types across these farms, with each land use in its own layer. Some of the polygons cover more than one farm.
I have done this for 11 different time periods over the past 60 years.

I need to create a set of results showing the area of each land use on each farm for each time epoch.

The clip tool allows me to determine the area covered by each land use on each farm, clipping  the polygons that cross farm boundaries.  However, if I use the farm boundary layer as a whole, it ignores the internal farm boundaries and does not classify by farm, so I have to do each farm separately. How can I work this in batch mode?

Comment: Use QGIS expressions with `intersection()` function to create the geometry of the intersection and from this calculate area. No clipping needed¨

Comment: By the way: from your description it's difficult to imagine the very data you have. What's the dirfference between between farm layer and internal farm boundaries? Posting  screenshot or - even better - share sample data would help understanding your point.